# html4 header tag position

Tags: html, seo

In all my websites XHTML source code, navigation and breadcrumbs appear below the content of the page yet visually they appear above. I am doing this as believe that in such way search engines find content more relevant.

In all the HTML5 examples I've seen, the order is classical:
header, body section, footer.
From SEO point of view, by working on HTML5 page, is it better to use classical tags order or the one I used till now in XHTML?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is more or less outdated advice.

Both Google and Bing have for many years now had the ability to render the DOM of the page and determine the actual layout of the page regardless of how the code is structured.

The old theory behind this technique was that search engines would only index the first 100kb or so of a page and typically that could be taken up by templated boilerplate code in some instances. This isn't a restriction that really exists anymore and to be honest if your pages are reaching that kind of filesize you probably have other things that you want to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better when the content with keywords appear earlier in the source code. For the general link structure it doesn't matter where main navigation links are placed.

But maybe search engines can weight structure different when using standard semantic ids like navigation, breadcrumbs, content and footer? In this case the position would be equal. Isn't the semantic thing one of the big advantages of HTML 5?!

Comment: The semantic is cerainly big advantage of HTML5 and I hope that search engines know to separate <header> content from what main content container div ( F.e. <div id="main">) contains.. and to rate the keywords from that container as high as if it would be in the beginning of the page. But I am still not sure in this theory.. This is what I want to know, if it is true or false.